# YouTube JS API - onStateChange

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube-api, jquery-events

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video on to one of our customer's websites and it needs to be able to show an image when it has finished playing. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to remove the containing div so an underlying image would be displayed.. but, I'm having a little difficulty. I have little knowledge of JavaScript and the chaps I'd normally hand this work over to are not available right now.

The problem I'm having is that the containing div is not being removed. After playback has finished, the player just displays a list of related videos - not magically disappearing!

Can anyone advise on the code I have written so far?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always"  };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO-ID?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3&autoplay=1&controls=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1",
                   "ytapiplayer", "621", "244", "8", null, null, params, atts);
// listen
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  var ytplayer = getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}
// closediv 
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   if (newState === 0){
        $('ytapiplayer').remove();
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector is wrong.

```
$('ytapiplayer').remove();
```

You are saying look for an html element called ytapiplayer, you need to use a `#` to say it is an id.

So the line should be:

```
$('#ytapiplayer').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response epascarello, alas it has not helped resolve my problem entirely - the onStateChange is being called but the div is not being removed. Any ideas?

Comment: So you fixed the code, did you add a debugging statement in there to see if the `newState=0`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been here for a while but his comment indicated it still does not work.

The other issue with the code is where he is testing newState he should be testing newState.data.

He has:

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   if (newState === 0){
        $('ytapiplayer').remove();
   }
}
```

needs to be:

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   if (newState.data === 0){
        $('ytapiplayer').remove();
   }
}
```